# Update a React class component when Next Js Link used

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components, state, react-props

### Original Post

I have a React class component that is used on a Next/JS Dynamic Path.  On initial load all is fine.  But there is a fringe use case that if I am on a page where that component is already mounted and then click a `Link` that is the same dynamic base as the component path but with different params, the component does not `unmount` and `getIntialProps` runs but it does not call the constructor to update the new state.

Path Examples:

Dynamic Pattern

```
/vos/[id]/[slug]
```

Initial Path

```
/vos/203dk2-d33d-3e3e3d/thisName
```

New path

```
/vos/554-34r4f-44d4e/aNewName
```

Events

```
1. component loads with initial props/state
2. user clicks Link to same component path but updated params
3. component lifecycles run to reset state but does not and does not unmount
4. 2-5 seconds pass... no activity
5. getIntialProps finally runs with new params
6. componentDidUpdate lifecycle called to update state with new props
```

I have also tried to change the `Link` to a `Router.push()` but have the same results.

Question:

1. Is there a way to force unmount a component to allow for a new instance of it to be created.
2. If not above, what would be the best way to handle this fringe case in the component lifecyces?  I have tried to update the state with a function in the `componentDidUpdate()` cycle but this gets a bit messy as it runs before the `SSR` is called so state management gets out of sync.

Code Example

```
static getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {

    const services = VerifiedOrganizationProfilePage.PageServices(ctx);

    const { lang: language, id: voId } = ctx.query as IProfilePagesQueryParams;

    // check VO page is existing
    // if VO owner or Admin
    let verifiedOrganization: IVerifiedOrganizationResponse | undefined;
    let user: IUserResponse | undefined;
    let isVoOwner: boolean = false;
    let isPlatformAdmin: boolean = false;
    let isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin: boolean = false;
    try {
      verifiedOrganization = await services.verifiedOrganizationService.getVerifiedOrganization(voId);

      if (!verifiedOrganization) throw new Error('No verified organization with that id was found!');

      const userId = await services.cognitoIdentityService.getUserIdInSession();
      if (userId) {
        user = await services.usersService.getUser(userId);

        isPlatformAdmin = AuthUtil.hasRoles(
          [ERole.PLATFORM_ADMIN],
          user.platformRoles
        );
        isVoOwner = OrganizationUtil.isVerifiedOrganizationOwner(
          verifiedOrganization.id,
          user
        );
        isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin = isVoOwner || isPlatformAdmin;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      NextUtil.redirectTo(
        '/not-found',
        ctx.res,
        HTTP_REDIRECT.TEMPORARY,
        language
      );
    }
    // fetch publicly visible data
    const { store } = ctx;

    store.dispatch(fetchCampaignsRequest({
      verified_organization_id: voId,
      limit: isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin ? EPaginationLimit.FIVE_HUNDRED : EPaginationLimit.DEFAULT,
    }, ctx));

    store.dispatch(fetchCausesRequest({
      verified_organization_id: voId,
      limit: EPaginationLimit.DEFAULT
    }, ctx));

    store.dispatch(fetchCommentsRequest({
      verified_organization_id: voId,
      limit: EPaginationLimit.DEFAULT
    }, ctx));

    store.dispatch(fetchUpdatesRequest({
      verified_organization_id: voId,
      limit: EPaginationLimit.DEFAULT
    }, ctx));

    // wait for redux saga updating state
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
        const state = store.getState();
        if (!state.campaign.isFetching && !state.cause.isFetching && !state.comment.isFetching && !state.update.isFetching) {
          unsubscribe();
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });

    return {
      user,
      voId,
      isVoOwner,
      isPlatformAdmin,
      verifiedOrganization,
      isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin,
      tabValue: EVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageTabs.CAMPAIGNS,
      pageUrl: NextUtil.getPageUrl(ctx),
    };
  }
...
constructor(props){

  super(props);
  this.state = {...this.props}

}
...
// used to check new props from VO if coming from another VO page and set the state
  static async getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: IVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageProps, prevState: IVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageState) {
    if (nextProps.voId !== prevState.voId) {
      return {
        voId: nextProps.voId,
        urlChanged: true,
        tabValue: EVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageTabs.CAMPAIGNS,
        isWaitingAdminApproval: false,
        isUserBothVoAndIpRepresentative: false,
        visibleBeneficiaryList: listResponse,
        beneficiaryGroups: listResponse,
        followingVerifiedOrganizations: {},
        beneficiaryBlockchainCSVData: undefined,
        userRating: undefined,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }
  }
...
async componentDidMount() {
    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', this.handleRouteChangeComplete); // to trigger callback beofre NEXT Router/Link executes
    await this.fetchPersonalData(); // method to fetch user specific data

}
...
async componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.urlChanged) {
      await this.fetchPersonalData();
    }
  }
...
componentWillUnmount() {
    Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', this.handleRouteChangeComplete);
}
...
// sets the current open tab to CAMPAIGNS if a VO navigates to a connected VO profile from a restricted tab
  public handleRouteChangeComplete = async (url: string) => {
    this.setState({tabValue: EVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageTabs.CAMPAIGNS,});
  }
...
public fetchPersonalData = async () => {
    const { voId, user, verifiedOrganization, isPlatformAdmin, isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin } = this.props;
    let isVoRepresentative: boolean = false;
    let isIpRepresentative: boolean = false;
    let isUserBothVoAndIpRepresentative: boolean = false;
    let isWaitingAdminApproval: boolean = false;
    let visibleBeneficiaryList: IListResponse<IBeneficiaryWithInvitationStatus> | undefined;
    let beneficiaryGroups: IListResponse<IGroup> | undefined;
    try {
      const services = VerifiedOrganizationProfilePage.PageServices();

      if (user) {

        isWaitingAdminApproval = verifiedOrganization.verifiedOrganizationStatus === EVerifiedOrganizationStatus.PENDING_PLATFORM_ADMIN_APPROVAL;

        // If Verified Organization is waiting for Admin Platform approval, only Platform Admin can see the page.
        if (isWaitingAdminApproval && !isPlatformAdmin) {
          throw new NotFoundError();
        }

        isVoRepresentative = AuthUtil.hasRoles(
          [ERole.VERIFIED_ORGANIZATION_REPRESENTATIVE],
          user.platformRoles
        );
        isIpRepresentative = AuthUtil.hasRoles(
          [ERole.IMPLEMENTING_PARTNER_REPRESENTATIVE],
          user.platformRoles
        );
        isUserBothVoAndIpRepresentative =
          isVoRepresentative && isIpRepresentative;
        // If Verified Organization is waiting for Admin Platform approval, only Platform Admin can see the page.
        if (isWaitingAdminApproval && !isPlatformAdmin) {
          throw new NotFoundError();
        }

        // add the prefix to the id so we can match the record in the Connections table.
        const prefixedId = EIdTypes.VERIFIED_ORGANIZATION.toUpperCase() + '#' + verifiedOrganization.id;

        // Fetch  data visible only to VoOwner and Aidonic
        const connections = [] as unknown as IListResponse<IConnectionVOIP>;

        if (isVoOwnerOrPlatformAdmin) {
          // Get from the API all the connections sent or received

          // Commenting this out as it calling twice the API. The call to the API is done from the Tab instead.
          // connections = await services.connectionsService.getVisibleConnectionsByOrganization(prefixedId);

          visibleBeneficiaryList = await services.beneficiaryService.getBeneficiariesVisibleToOrganization(prefixedId);
          beneficiaryGroups = await services.beneficiaryGroupsService.getBeneficiaryGroupsList(prefixedId, {limit: EPaginationLimit.THIRTY});
        }
        const follows = await services.followsService.getFollowsList({
          user_id: user.id
        });

        const [followingVerifiedOrganizations] = mapFollowsByKey(follows, [
          'verifiedOrganizationId'
        ]);

        const userRating = await services.ratingsService.getRatingList({
          user_id: user.id,
          verified_organization_id: verifiedOrganization.id
        });

        this.setState({
          voId,
          connections,
          tabValue: EVerifiedOrganizationProfilePageTabs.CAMPAIGNS,
          beneficiaryGroups,
          isWaitingAdminApproval,
          visibleBeneficiaryList,
          followingVerifiedOrganizations,
          isUserBothVoAndIpRepresentative,
          userRating: userRating && userRating[0],
          isLoading: false,
          urlChanged: false
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error in data fetching on VO profile page: ', e);
    }
  }
```

### Update

I have split the props from the state to maintain one source of true and used `getDerivedStateFromProps()` to catch the change and call `fetchPersonalData()`.  All working well.

The only issue is it seems to take twice as long to load the new updated props/state than initial load.  Thoughts?

Comment: "it seems to take twice as long to load the new updated props/state than initial load" - Do you experience that same behaviour when running the production build (`next build && next start`)?

Comment: @juliomalves I am.  Marginally faster but still noticeably longer than when the component is first mounted.  What I think is happening is that when the route changes the component "reloads" from `getIntialProps()` (never `unmounts`) and all is fine.  But in-between the return of `getInitialProps()` and the `comonentDidUpdate()` life cycle, there is a bottle neck. New props are passed in, but the state is not updated as quickly.  I am stumped.

Comment: Can you show the code for `getInitialProps `, `fetchPersonalData` and `handleRouteChangeComplete`? Any time consuming operations happening in those?

Comment: @juliomalves sure I will post it above.  `getInitialProps()` has a couple redux calls but that all seems to execute as normal.  It is after they are returned that the bottle neck happens.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down to the two API calls in `fetchPersonalData()`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
For my case this was cause by a API call in the lifecycle.  Framework worked fine.